# How to call a non-static method from a function pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a class "Person" like so:

```
typedef void (*action)();
typedef std::unordered_map<int, action> keybindMap; // maps keycodes to functions

class Person {
    keybindMap keybinds;
    void doSomething();
}
```

I use this to call the functions at the right times:

```
iter = keybinds.find(event.key.keysym.sym); // event.key.keysym.sym is the key code
if (iter != keybinds.end())
{
    (*iter->second)(); // call whatever function that key is bound to.
}
```

To bind a key, I used `keybinds.insert_or_assign(SDLK_a, doSomething)`. However, this doesn't work (because doSomething is non-static). How do I change the binding code and/or the `(*iter->second)()` part so that I can call something equivalent to `person.doSomething`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-static method requires an object to call it on. An ordinary function pointer doesn't have room to hold a reference to an object.

If you change your map to hold `std::function` instead, you can then use `std::bind()` or a lambda to associate an object with a method pointer, eg:

```
using action = std::function<void()>;
using keybindMap = std::unordered_map<int, action>;

class Person {
    keybindMap keybinds;
    void doSomething();
};

... 

Person p, otherP; //must outlive the map...
p.keybinds[...] = [&otherP](){ otherP.doSomething(); } 

...

iter = keybinds.find(event.key.keysym.sym);
if (iter != keybinds.end()) {
    iter->second();
}
```

On the other hand, if all of the target methods are in the same class/object, you can use a plain method pointer instead of `std::function`, which will reduce some overhead, eg:

```
class Person {
    using action = void (Person::*)();
    using keybindMap = std::unordered_map<int, action>; 

    keybindMap keybinds;
    void doSomething();
};

... 

keybinds[...] = &Person::doSomething;

...

iter = keybinds.find(event.key.keysym.sym);
if (iter != keybinds.end()) {
    (this->*(iter->second))();
}
```

Comment: To follow up, if you don't want to use std::function, the prototype for a method pointer (which is distinctively different from a function pointer) is `ReturnType (ClassName::*)(Parameters)`. Its calling convention is `(instance->*methodPointer)(parameters)`, if memory serves. `std::function` is far easier though.

Comment: How much overhead does `std::function` really incur?

Comment: The second code doesn't run; the compiler says that Person isn't defined in this scope at the first line.

Comment: @Thuong I have updated my example

Comment: @ThuongVo: *"How much overhead does std::function really incur?"* Similar to a virtual call for `operator()` and for destruction. (and allocation if you pass *"big"* object).

Comment: For handling keyboard events it probably is negligible ...